# Handling a series of named variables of the same type

Tags: c#

The following example is bad, because it has code repetition. For example, if we later need to `CheckExpirationDate` before drinking, we need to add the function call in multiple places. If we need to add `charley` and `stan` to the party, the code gets huge quickly.

```
if (john != designatedDriver)
{
    beer.Open();
    john.Drink(beer);
}
if (bob != designatedDriver)
{
    cider.Open();
    bob.Drink(cider);
}
```

The solution could be to build an array of these objects. That's really easy if you need to operate one object at a time. For example, if everyone is passing around a single bottle of beer:

```
beer.Open();
foreach (Dude i in new Dude[] { john, bob })
{
    i.Drink(beer);
}
```

To rewrite the original example, we can use a `KeyValuePair`. Not particularly pretty, but well worth it for more than two dudes or if the drinking procedure is long enough (wine tasting).

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Dude, Booze> i in KeyValuePair<Dude, Booze>[] {
    new KeyValuePair<Dude, Booze>(john, beer),
    new KeyValuePair<Dude, Booze>(bob, cider) })
{
    if (i.Key != designatedDriver)
    {
        i.Value.Open();
        i.Key.Drink(i.Value);
    }
}
```

**But what if we need to operate three or more objects at a time?** For example, john drinks beer *and* eats nachos. We can resort to declaring custom types, but that would make the code dependent on other code somewhere far away. We could put each type in its own array and do a good old `for` loop and access the objects with indexes, but that would mean creating named arrays (`Dude[] dudes = new Dude { john, bob };`).

What I'm asking is, **is there some fancy C# trick that would let me do this very cleanly and compactly?** Anonymous types? Something?

Comment: Your first and third code samples are not equivalent, as you say they are. In the third sample, bob never drinks his cider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned anonymous types, this should do the trick:

```
foreach (var i in new[] {
                           new{Dude=john, Booze=beer, Food=nachos},
                           new{Dude=bob, Booze=cider, Food=chips}
                        })
{
        if (i.Dude != designatedDriver)
        {
                i.Booze.Open();
                i.Dude.Drink(i.Booze);
                i.Dude.Eat(i.Food);
        }
}
```

Comment: The designated driver doesn't get to eat either? That's just mean!

Comment: Hmmm... To protect from food poisoning?

Answer (score 0):

Well.... assuming you had three separate collections of Dudes, Boozes, and Foods, you could use a LINQ query and create an anonymous type. Then you wouldn't have to worry about creating a new type and any dependencies that might be created by that. Here's an example:

```
// assumes existing collections called "boozes" "dudes" and "foods"
var qry = from booze in boozes
          from dude in dudes
          from food in foods
          select new {
               Dude = dude,
               Booze = booze,
               Food = food
          };

foreach(var item in qry)
{
    if(!item.Dude.IsDesignatedDriver)
    {
        item.Booze.Open();
        item.Food.Cook();
        item.Dude.Drink(item.Booze);
        item.Dude.Eat(item.Food);
    }
}
```

The drawbacks:

- the anonymous type must be used from within the calling block -- you can't return anonymous types from a method.
- you need pre-existing collections.
- The code listed creates a pairing for every dude, food, and booze option. You may not actually want that. A where clause may help there, however.

Comment: Why not just add a "where !dude.IsDesignatedDriver" to the top query?

Comment: This gives the Cartesian product of dude x drink x food, when I think you meant to have them zipped. We're adding a Zip sequence operator to the extension methods library for the next version of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much control you have over your classes, but I would create an Interface (or use a base class, depending on specific needs) called IInjestible (or something), and then give each dude a list(List<>, IEnumerable<>, whatever) of type IInjestible.  Then you could do something like:

```
foreach (Dude dude in Dudes)
{
  foreach(IInjestible snack in Snacks)
  {
    snack.Injest(dude);
  }
}
```

Or, with a base class Snack:

```
foreach(Dude dude in Dudes)
{
  foreach(Snack snack in Snacks)
  {
    if(snack is Drink) {dude.drink(snack);}
    if(snack is Food) {dude.eat(snack);}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that this is something that could be fixed by changing the design of the application assuming that that is something that can be done. What you can do is create an interface like the following:

```
interface IConsumable{ };
```

Then you can have the each of your consumable classes implement this interface, so you would have:

```
class Beer : IConsumable, IDrink {
    public void Drink { ...; }
}

class Nachos : IConsumable, IFood {
    public void East { ...; }
}
```

Then in your KeyValuePair you can send a Dude and an array of IConsumable objects like this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Dude, IConsumable[]> i in KeyValuePair<Dude, IConsumale[]>[] {
    foreach(IConsumable consumable in i.Value) {   
        if(consumable is IFood){
            //Code for food
        }
        if(consumable is IDrink){
            //Code for drinks
        }
        //You can even be more specific
        if(consumable is Beer){ //Code for Beer }
    }
}
```

This might not be the best design, but it is a step forward. I apologize if the code doesn't work as written but I was in a hurry.

Hope this helps.